# Почему gitlab-runner запускает executor докера руби, хотя указан shell?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Вот файл gitlab-ci

```
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - cp -R build/* /var/www/html
```

при пуше запускает пайплайн в котором

```
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:28
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
```

из-за этого ранер не видит npm

```
npm install
/bin/bash: line 110: npm: command not found
```

Вот файл конфига с сервера config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
name = "test"
url = "https://gitlab.com/"
token = "123321123"
executor = "shell"
shell = "bash"
[runners.custom_build_dir]
[runners.cache]
[runners.cache.s3]
[runners.cache.gcs]
[runners.cache.azure]
```

Comment: Перед `stage`'ом укажите явно образ: `image: node:14.15.0-alpine3.10`

Comment: мне не нужно чтобы все в докере собиралось, я хочу чтобы сборка запускалась c shell executor

Comment: Присвойте shell-runner-у тэг и укажите в джобе тэг этого shell-runner. Не нашёл его в вашем текущем посте, поэтому видимо и запускается рубишный docker-executor по умолчанию. Про тэги можно почитать тут https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags Если не поможет - обновите скрипт в посте и добавьте информацию - пошарен ли shell-раннер тому проекту в котором вы хотите запускать джобу в shell-executor.